# How do I copy multiple folders to another path with a batch file?

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, command-line

How to make it go through certain folders(ex. 1-8 on the drive E:) and their trees and copy them on F: in the batch file(my doesn't work):

```
set drive=E:
for %%a in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8) do (
  set folder=%%a
   for /R "%drive%\%%a" %%b in (*) do (
        copy "%%b" %drive%\%folder%
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the syntax you want is

```
for %%F in (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8) do (
    xcopy /e e:\%%F  f:\
)
```

Comment: it's copying files in his folders

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to set and reuse an environment variable in a loop. This cannot work since `cmd` expands all environment variables when *parsing* a command, not when running it. So you need to enable delayed expansion:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set drive=E:
for %%a in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8) do (
  set folder=%%a
  for /R "%drive%\%%a" %%b in (*) do (
    copy "%%b" %drive%\!folder! 
  )
)
```

(you were also missing a few closing parenthesis, I added those for you)

But you could just as well use `%%a`. It should still exist in the inner loop ...

```
set drive=E:
for %%a in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8) do (
  for /R "%drive%\%%a" %%b in (*) do (
    copy "%%b" %drive%\%%a 
  )
)
```